# Lync Server 2010 SDK sample application error: Application not authorized

Tags: lync-server-2010

I have installed and configured the Lync Server 2010. When I run the example to Lync Server SDK (SipSnoop) and press the button Connect, I get an error:

```
- EXCEPTION (2:23:20 PM) -
Application not authorized.
Queue could not be created.
Access denied.
```

All services of Lync Server running normally, messages and phone calls are sent without any problems. SipSnoop run on Front-end server.

Script-only exampels from this SDK runs correctly.

What i need to do to run SipSnoop correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check the readme

If you see the "Queue could not be opened Access Denied" error message, check whether
 the logged on user is part of the "RTC Server Applications" local group. If not, add it, logout and login and retry

Where is the "RTC Server Applications" local group?
On the server which you run your application on. click:

- Control pannel-->change account type --> Advanced --> Advanced -->group -->Groups

### check the uri

- The appUri in SIPSnoop.am should be same as the the uri you supplied by this command "new-csserverapplication"

Answer (score 1):

You should started with elevated privileges ("run as administrator")

To run The Visual Studio with administrator privileges:

1. Run the *.exe of the application from the bin folder by "run as administrator"
2. Start to attach the *.exe to the debugger from "Debug ==> Attach to process"
3. the visual studio will ask you to start with the administrator previlege